# Does router radiation increase with bandwidth or signal strength?

Tags: wireless-router

Does the amount of low-level radiation emitted by residential-class wireless routers (examples: Netgear, Linksys) increase with larger bandwidth, dual-banding, or longer range/signal strength? Example: does a Netgear n750 emit more low-level radiation than a Netgear n300?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. Having the capability to handle larger bandwidth or greater range doesn't change the emitted radiation for the same usage. A router with greater range or higher bandwidth may be *capable* of emitting more radiation if the conditions require the use of the greater range or higher bandwidth capabilities. But if the conditions are the same, the emissions will be roughly the same.